# "!" illegal operation on bound member function expression

Tags: c++, file

Well i am reading my file in the class and when i do the following it gives me error. Please suggest any solution to this.

```
void write2file (string water)
{
    ofstream write;
    write.open ("D:\\Assignments\Water.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
    {
        write<<water<<endl;

    }
    write.close();

}


     void DisplayW ()
     {
         ifstream read ("D:\\Assignments\Water.txt", ios::in|ios::app);

         while (!read.eof) //ERROR at this point//
         {
             read >> Elements[i];
             cout<<"Elements are: "<<Elements[i]<<endl;
         }

     }
```

Comment: And it should be `"D:\\Assignments\\Water.txt"`.

Comment: @herohuyongtao: Or just "water.txt" so that when you hand in the assignment it will actually run wherever it is put as long as the text file is in the current working directory! ;)

Answer (score 4):

Solution:

```
 void DisplayW ()
 {
     ifstream read ("D:\\Assignments\\Water.txt", ios::in|ios::app);

     // while (!read.eof) //ERROR at this point//
     // better:
     while(!read.eof()) // I think this is what you intended to write
     {
         read >> Elements[i];
         cout<<"Elements are: "<<Elements[i]<<endl;
     }
 }
```

Better solution:

```
    i = 0;
    while(read >> Elements[i++]);
```

Explanation:

```
    read >> Elements[i];
```

performs:

- get int from stream and set into elements
- set i/o state based on success of operation
- return ostream&

  ```
          i++;
  ```
- advance to next element to be read;

  ```
  while( [[returned ostream&]] )
  ```
- convert ostream to boolean; this checks ostream state (i/o state based on success of operation) and eof bit and returns true if both are ok.
- the while evaluates to true and reads into the next index.

At the end of the loop, `i` will count your elements.

Solution based on your code:

```
i = 0;
while(read >> Elements[i])
    cout<<"Elements are: "<<Elements[i++]<<endl; // note i++ as
                                                 // the last operation
```

Comment: Oh mine thats Exactly what i was trying to do. Thanku sooo very much :-)

Answer (score 2):

You missed the function call syntax.

use

```
     while (!read.eof())
```

instead of

```
     while (!read.eof)
```

Answer (score 1):

`.eof` is a member function. You must call it.

```
while (!read.eof())
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you you're trying to use `!` on a member function.  You probably meant to use it on the result of calling the member function:

```
while (!read.eof())
```